# Как по опции "services.SERVICE_NAME.volumes" в docker-compose.yml понять, сколько в контейнере будет volum-ов?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Анализирую учебный пример:

```
version: '3'

services:
  webpack:
    build: ./docker/webpack
    volumes:
      - ./src:/my_webpack/src
      - ./dist:/my_webpack/dist
      - ./docker/webpack/package.json:/my_webpack/package.json
      - ./docker/webpack/webpack.config.js:/my_webpack/webpack.config.js
    ports:
      - 2000:2000
```

Мне, как новичку в Docker, показалось странным, что в массиве `volumes` первые два элемента - пути директорий, а остальные - пути файлов. Странно это потому, что непонятно, сколько volume-ов в контейнере. Насколько я знаю, volume - это папка, но в уроках для новичков подробности обычно опускаются, потому ответ "3 вольюма" может быть неверным.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для просмотра всего списка `volumes`

```
docker volume ls
```

Есть ещё команда

```
docker inspect <container_id|container_name>
```

Но получить количество конкретно в одном контейнере не получится.

Не стоит использовать `volumes` для подключения файлов. Тогда подключайте всю директорию

```
volumes:
  - ./src:/my_webpack/src
  - ./dist:/my_webpack/dist
  - ./docker/webpack:/my_webpack
```

Либо в Dockerfile используйте `COPY` для копирования отдельный файлов.

Comment: Не ответили на вопрос, поставленный в заголовке.

Comment: Обновил свой ответ.